# Display tag ver 1.2

Tags: struts, displaytag

I have an issue with displaytag 1.2 and struts.

I am using pagination of display tag. when i 'go' in page 2  and I click sumbit I lost all the value of the list.

How can I keep track of those values?

I mean, in my action i have only the value of the elements current displayed, I need all the value.

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `value list pattern` as they said at their [**site**](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html) then you need to handle partial values from your customized class which will implement the `org.displaytag.pagination.PaginatedList interface`.

But there is another way too where you don't have to do anything except giving some parameter.
Read this [**Doc**](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html) carefully